# You can call the same line of code for TPT and TPH but how is the "under the hood" implementation different?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, inheritance, .net-core, entity-framework-core

When using TPT or TPH inheritance in EF6 you can execute code like:

```
`WarehouseEmployee wEmp = new WarehouseEmployee();
_context.Employees.Add(wEmp);
```

In this example, WarehouseEmployee derives from Employee and Employee is an abstract class. Here Employees would be a `DbSet<Employee> Employees` in the derived `DbContext` class.

I think the part that is throwing me off is you could call the same exact method in both TPT, TPC, or TPH but it works differently under the hood for each. Where is that difference happening and what are the implementation differences?

Comment: For EF6 - [Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt). For EF Core - simply not implemented yet. I guess you know EF Core is full EF rewrite and in active development, so many EF6 features are missing.

Comment: @IvanStoev Please see the additional Info section I added

Comment: @IvanStoev upvote is for the helpful link. I really like how the author explains it.

Comment: When i was trying to read about them , i ended up bookmarking these two links for simple and detailed explanation . Hope this helps you understand how tables are created and what are the advantage/disadvantage of each : 1.[Inheritance Strategy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/04/14/tip-12-how-to-choose-an-inheritance-strategy/) 2.[Inheritance in EF](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

Answer (score 1):

In [this feature request for TPT](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2266), the EF team has moved from

> The feeling from our team is that TPT is generally an anti-pattern and results in significant performance issues later on. While enabling it may make some folks "happier" to start with it ultimately just leads to issues. We are willing to consider it though, so we're leaving this open and will consider it based on the feedback we get. (Rowan Miller, 29 May 2015)

to

> Triage: We do plan to do this based on feedback from the community. Purely due to time constraints it won't be in the initial release (just TPH will be in). (Rowan Miller, 3 Oct 2015)

and finally to

> TPT support is something we plan to implement, but it is a big cross-cutting feature. I can't say that it will be in the next release following 2.1 because there are many other competing features that are also high priority. However, each release we also think about which building blocks we need to get closer to being able to support these big cross-cutting features. So we are getting closer, but it's going to take some more time. (Arthur Vickers, 12 Feb 2018)

So it seems you have to be patient or otherwise look for other implementation strategies (for example `1:0..1` associations).

I don't think that the question how EF6 does it under the hood is really relevant. For one, what would you gain by knowing that? But, more importantly, EF-core is a total remake of Entity Framework. No chance at all that EF6 code can be ported to EF-core code.

Comment: My coworker asked me why we couldn't use TPT in EF Core and the best response I could give was" it isn't supported." I'm having trouble putting in to words what exactly I want to know. I think what is throwing me off is the methods used in tph are the same that are used in tpt. E.g. OfType() -- but when used on DbSets in a tph setup they work... But run that same code in tpt and it doesn't work. Does that make sense?

Comment: But "it isn't supported" is also the *only* answer. I don't know what else there is to say. It's EF's decision how to translate LINQ into SQL. Different inheritance models (in EF6) can be accessed by identical LINQ queries. It's not the LINQ query that makes the difference, it's the translation under the hood. Likewise, identical CUD operations (in the class model) can be translated into completely different insert/update statements. EF Core only offers one translation.

Comment: That's the link (no pun intended) I was missing

Comment: even better would to know what triggers the difference; is it the TPT T4 template in EF that sets some flag that linq uses to know how to generate the query? I'm assuming I could check out the .net 4.x reference and look at linq code to maybe see the difference between it and core

Comment: No, it's purely the mapping instructions, either given by code-first mappings or by mapping metadata in an EDMX file. In EF6, database-first, the T4 template just generates the requested metadata depending on how the inheritance is [shaped in the design surface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618293%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: So you're saying that .NET 4.x EF C# would generate SQL dependent on the mapping metadata, meaning it would know that if the metadata was mapped in TPT style to do a TPT query? Which means that while you may be able to add c# inheritance to your generated Model classes(database first) in EF Core LINQ will be unable to generate the SQL in TPT style because it only knows how to generate TPH LINQ to SQL? Likewise if I were to create iheritance  via `EntityTypeBuilder.HasBaseType(String)` in EF Core, it would could only create TPH tables in the database, correct?